# Converting IQueryable to ObservableCollection, must know how

Tags: c#, datagrid, observablecollection

The question is why does the null reference occur for the observable collection? The error occurs when I try to add item to the obscollection.

Note: I have to know how to give all items present in datagrid to observable collection.

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

line:- "good.Add(temp_table);" in button one click

### .xaml.cs

```
Web.DomainService1 oservice = new Web.DomainService1();
public static ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE> good = new ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE>();

public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;

    EntityQuery<Web.EMP_TABLE> q = oservice.GetEMP_TABLE_OBVQuery();
    LoadOperation<Web.EMP_TABLE> l = oservice.Load(q);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = l.Entities;
}



private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE> good = 
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE>;
    Web.EMP_TABLE temp_table = new Web.EMP_TABLE();
    temp_table.SALARY = "new_sal";
    temp_table.EMP_NAME = "new_name";
    temp_table.EMP_NO = "new_num";
    good.Add(temp_table);
}
```

### .xaml

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="116" Name="dataGrid2" Width="539" />
```

### The DomainService function

```
public ObservableCollection<EMP_TABLE> GetEMP_TABLE_OBV()
{
    var value = from c in this.ObjectContext.EMP_TABLE
                select c;
    ObservableCollection<EMP_TABLE> result = new ObservableCollection<EMP_TABLE>(value);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: remember that nobody on stackoverflow is paid to answer questions so any demands or expectations on responsiveness doens't make sense.

Comment: "recently have noticed soflow users dont answer as fast as in past" Well, that's too bad.

Comment: It might be, that people don't answer so fast TO YOUR QUESTIONS, because you don't put any effort into formulating them? What the heck is with all the code? Most of it has nothing to do with the question. You are being ignorant, therefore my downvote.

Comment: well atleast down voting is done fast

Comment: You don't seem to get it, do you?

Comment: okay sir Daniel according to your guidelines  i am editting the question, but please help. i am stuck here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your edit and reading of the comments, I don't see, how this should work:
As others have pointed out, your cast is failing.
You say, you pass an ObservableCollection, but in fact, you don't do it, have a look here:
In your ctor:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = l.Entities;
```

`l.Entities` is most likely an `IQueryable`, not an `ObservableCollection`

Later, you are trying to cast `dataGrid1.ItemsSource`, which is failing.
You showed us the code of `GetEMP_TABLE_OBV` which returns an `ObservableCollection`, but I don't see any usage of that method.

Comment: yes the cast is failing, there is a null reference, but this line " EntityQuery<Web.EMP_TABLE> q = oservice.GetEMP_TABLE_OBVQuery(); " uses the GetEMP_TABLE_OBV OR NOT?

Comment: okay, then when i try "oservice.GetEMP_TABLE_OBV()" DOESNOT COME, is there a way to correct this? clearly, how can i call this method?

Comment: i am kind of totally confused here,  when i try to use pure silveranabled wcf services, the contraints of the database such as LENGTH, PRIMARY KEY(editable(false), etc do not work. when i use domain services, i cannot get my data as an observable collection

Comment: I have no idea, because I don't understand your code or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i am trying to pass the select items from the table to the silverlight client, such that they appear in the grid, maintain entitytracking and can be used as an observable collection

Comment: You cant get an Observable collection back. You need to create your own then add the items that are returned yourself.

Answer (score 5):

```
ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE> good = dataGrid1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Web.EMP_TABLE>;
```

When you use "as" instead of (TYPE) to cast, no exception is thrown if the cast fails. Your variable is simply set to null.
Your cast is failing.

Answer (score 3):

datagrid1.ItemSource is not an ObservableCollection  so your cast fails and good is therefor null.

You have to inspect what type datagrid1.ItemSource actually hold  (it is the type of the Entities property on the LoadOperation type ) and cast to that type

Comment: but i passed an observable collection in domain service, okay so how to achieve this?